# Using structs instead of floats for clarity

Tags: c#, struct

We am working on an application which involves boats. Internally our code measures speed in meters-per-second (m/s), but in the user interface it's displayed in knots. Speed values, whether in m/s or knots, are stored in floats.

```
float speedKnots = speedSlider.value;
float speedMS = Units.KnotsToMetersPerSecond(speedKnots);
boat.Speed = speedMS;
```

Despite our best efforts to use good naming conventions, team members (including myself) occasionally forget to convert between m/s and knots, e.g.

```
boat.Speed = speedSlider.Value; //bad code - forgot the unit conversion!
```

These issues can be time-consuming to find and fix. One solution I've thought of is to create structs for `MetersPerSecond` and `Knots` which just wrap floats:

```
public struct Knots {
    public Knots(float value) { this.Value = value; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator MetersPerSecond(Knots k) => k.Value * 0.514444;
    public static implicit operator float(Knots k) => k.Value;
    //other operator overloading omitted for brevity
}
public struct MetersPerSecond {
    public MetersPerSecond(float value) { this.Value = value; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator Knots(MetersPerSecond mps) => mps.Value * 1.94384;
    public static implicit operator float(MetersPerSecond mps) => mps.Value;
    //other operator overloading omitted for brevity
}
```

This feels like a safer, more explicit approach to me. However, I am concerned that it is over-engineering. I can't recall ever seeing this strategy used in any language. It seems like the standard practice is just to use built-in numeric types like `float` and remember to call unit-conversion functions.

Is it bad programming practice to create structs that wrap a single numeric value, with implicit type conversion, just to ensure that unit-conversions aren't forgotten? Are there any side-effects to consider which may not be immediately obvious?

Comment: I am hoping this question is not too subjective, but realize there may not be a widely agreed-upon answer.

Comment: Side note: bidirectional implicit conversion operators are a bad idea. At least one direction should be explicit. Look for the conversion that has the greater potential for loss of accuracy and make that one explicit. If there's equal potential for loss of accuracy, they should both be explicit.

Comment: Another option would be to pick one value as the standard and parse values to your type. `BoatSpeed FromKnots(float knots)` and `BoatSpeed FromMetersPerSecond(float mps)` and format to the desired units `float ToKnots()`, and `float ToMPS()` and it wouldn't matter how you store it internally.

Comment: "I can't recall ever seeing this strategy used in any language" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure...

Comment: `float` operations are often done as `double` and then converted back. If you have bidirectional implicit operators, you may get two conversions happening without noticing it, even though the original form could've been preserved and any loss of accuracy from the conversions avoided.

Comment: Another alternative is to use the Web Forms [`Unit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit) type as an example, where the measurement `Value` and the `UnitType` are kept together and unit conversions return another `Unit` instance with a different `UnitType` value. This allows you to pass a value in either unit instead of having different overloads for the two types.

Comment: struct Speed {} with measurement type looks like a more common solution

Comment: I would second the suggestion by @juharr. The [`TimeSpan`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,865ef7b89f41b632) struct comes to mind as a good example. I can envision creating a similar struct called `BoatSpeed`, making the `Speed` property of that type, and then writing code similar to: `boat.Speed = BoatSpeed.FromKnots(20);` and `boat.Speed = BoatSpeed.FromMetersPerSecond(20);`.

Comment: @madreflection My thought with the implicit conversion was that we only need to convert when reading knots from the UI or displaying knots to the UI; all other math involving the speeds happens in m/s. However, I can see how bidirectional implicit conversion might lead other team members to treat knots and m/s as interchangeable and start letting knots into the internal math.

Comment: @juharr I agree with several others that your solution seems better than the strategy I was considering. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: Side note: you may want to review existing post on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com on the topic https://www.bing.com/search?q=units%20of%20measure%20site%3Asoftwareengineering.stackexchange.com too..

Comment: One more concern - do you care to get nicely looking values or mathematically precise? It's always funny to read translated articles between MPH and km/h countries like "this car gets to roughly 241.4016 km/h"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I wasn't sure what search terms to use. The math is precise (allowing for loss of precision during unit conversion) and we use format strings when displaying in the UI (e.g. `label.Text = knots.ToString("N1"))`

Comment: There a library on GitHub called [`Units.Net`](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet) that has both "meters per second" and "knot" units defined (see the [`Speed.json`](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet/blob/master/Common/UnitDefinitions/Speed.json) file). I have no personal experience with it, but it may come in handy here.

Comment: The only thing I'd change about your approach is removing the implicit float<->unit conversions or make them explicit. It seems like they are just reintroducing the problem you stated you are trying to avoid.

Comment: I think these comments that point to specific units of measure implementations are missing the point. **Every** good code base defines dedicated types for its core entities, and the best code bases use builtin, general types sparingly. Contrary to what you suspect this is an incredibly well established, widespread technique (though it's certainly not widespread enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to create a struct that uses one or the other unit of measure as a "base" and which then always converts that unit of measure to the other when needed. The importance of this is that the base unit is what we can use for comparisons, additions, subtractions, etc.

**Note:** for doing comparisons, we should use either an integer or decimal for our base type, since floats and doubles are *binary* floating-point types, and will result in rounding errors.

We could add some `static` methods that create an instance of the struct based on any unit of measure we want, as well as some `Add` and `Subtract` methods that return new instances of the struct by adding the base units together. We could also override common math operators as well.

Here's an example that uses `MetersPerSecond` as the base unit, but which can be created from either meters per second or knots:

```
public struct Speed : IEquatable<Speed>, IComparable<Speed>
{
    // This is the "base" unit that will be used for comparisons with other instances
    public decimal MetersPerSecond { get; private set; }
    public decimal Knots => MetersPerSecond * MpsToKnot;

    private const decimal MpsToKnot = 1.943844M;

    // Static methods to create instances of this class
    public static Speed FromMetersPerSecond(decimal metersPerSecond)
    {
        return new Speed { MetersPerSecond = metersPerSecond};
    }

    public static Speed FromKnots(decimal knots)
    {
        return FromMetersPerSecond(knots / MpsToKnot);
    }

    // Mathematic and comparison methods and operators
    public Speed Add(Speed speed)
    {
        return new Speed { MetersPerSecond = this.MetersPerSecond + speed.MetersPerSecond };
    }

    public Speed Subtract(Speed speed)
    {
        return new Speed { MetersPerSecond = this.MetersPerSecond - speed.MetersPerSecond };
    }

    public int CompareTo(Speed other)
    {
        return MetersPerSecond.CompareTo(other.MetersPerSecond);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Speed)) return false;
        return Equals((Speed) obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(Speed other)
    {
        return MetersPerSecond.Equals(other.MetersPerSecond);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return MetersPerSecond.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static Speed operator -(Speed s)
    {
        return new Speed { MetersPerSecond = -s.MetersPerSecond };
    }

    public static Speed operator -(Speed s1, Speed s2)
    {
        return s1.Subtract(s2);
    }

    public static Speed operator +(Speed s)
    {
        return s;
    }

    public static Speed operator +(Speed s1, Speed s2)
    {
        return s1.Add(s2);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Speed s1, Speed s2)
    {
        return s1.MetersPerSecond == s2.MetersPerSecond;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Speed s1, Speed s2)
    {
        return s1.MetersPerSecond != s2.MetersPerSecond;
    }

    public static bool operator <(Speed s1, Speed s2)
    {
        return s1.MetersPerSecond < s2.MetersPerSecond;
    }

    public static bool operator <=(Speed s1, Speed s2)
    {
        return s1.MetersPerSecond <= s2.MetersPerSecond;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Speed s1, Speed s2)
    {
        return s1.MetersPerSecond > s2.MetersPerSecond;
    }

    public static bool operator >=(Speed s1, Speed s2)
    {
        return s1.MetersPerSecond >= s2.MetersPerSecond;
    }
}
```

Then, in use, we would have a `Boat` class that has `Speed` defined with this struct:

```
public class Boat
{
    public Speed Speed { get; set; }

    // Rest of implementation omitted
}
```

And now we have to be explicit about the unit of measure when specifying the `Speed`:

```
boat.Speed = Speed.FromKnots(speedSlider.value);
```

Comment: This is a good strategy and I ended up doing something similar. One point of note - the extra precision of decimal is overkill for most types of software, and the performance cost compared to floats or doubles is very high. Most apps aren't going to bottleneck on it, but it's still worth noting.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, I didn't use `decimal` for performance, I used it for doing equality comparisons. You won't get accurate results using `==` with binary floating point values. If there's some way to represent the "base" unit of measure as a `long`, that would probably be better.

Comment: Fair point. I think in our case the only time we'd need to do an equality comparison is `if (speed.MetersPerSecond == 0)`. FYI I am using floats because they are precise enough for our purposes and our engine (Unity) does everything in floats. When I do need to compare float equality I often do a fuzzy-equals (`if Math.Abs(a - b) < threshold`)